# docker images at different network by using same image name?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

what is the best approach if i want to maintain 2 different environment, some of the images are same at both environment.

environment A at docker network A:

1. docker image kafka
2. docker image sql
3. docker image dot net application A

environment B at docker network B:

1. docker image kafka
2. docker image sql
3. docker image dot net application B

currently, i use docker compose env A yml to bring up env A.
then when i want to use env B, i need to prune env A.

i do not want to prune env A, but just stop them, then up them when i needed.

i have tried to stop env A, but when i up env B, error occured due to the same image file defined for docker image kafka, and docker image sql, although different network name is given in the yml file.

sample yml file of env A

```
version: '3'
networks:
  spm:
services:  
  postgres:
    networks: 
      - pm
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: 1234
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 1234

  zookeeper:
    networks: 
      - spm
    image: zookeeper
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN: 1

  kafka:
    networks: 
      - spm
    image: kafka
    hostname: kafka
    container_name: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: 'yes'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka

  dotnetapp A:
    networks: 
      - spm
    build:
        context: ../
        dockerfile: ./A/Dockerfile
    image: dotnetapp:latest
    hostname: dotnetapp
    depends_on:
      - db
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
    ports:
      - "8015:8015"
    container_name: dotnetapp
```